# Extracting a certain substring (email address)

Tags: r, regex, substring

I'm attempting to pull some a certain from a variable that looks like this:

```r
v1 <- c("Persons Name <personsemail@email.com>","person 2 <person2@email.com>")
```

(this variable has hundreds of observations)

I want to eventually make a second variable that pulls their email to give this output:

```r
v2 <- c("personsemail@email.com", "person2@email.com")
```

How would I do this? Is there a certain package I can use? Or do I need to make a function incorporating `grep` and `substr`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those look like what R might call a "person". There is an `as.person()` function that can split out the email address. For example

```
v1 <- c("Persons Name <personsemail@email.com>","person 2 <person2@email.com>")
unlist(as.person(v1)$email)
# [1] "personsemail@email.com" "person2@email.com"
```

For more information, see the `?person` help page.

Comment: Whaaaaaaaaaaaaat? :O [How do you find these functions?!]

Comment: @zx8754 Yeah, there are a lot of crazy functions on there. I think i learned of this one by helping someone that was trying to subset these collections a long time ago on this very site. They have some odd behaviors.

Answer (score 3):

One option with `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(v1, "(?<=\\<)[^>]+")
#[1] "personsemail@email.com" "person2@email.com"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can look for the pattern "anything**, then <, then (anything), then >, then anything" and replace that pattern with the part between the parentheses, indicated by \1 (and an extra \ to escape).

```
sub('.*<(.*)>.*', '\\1', v1)
# [1] "personsemail@email.com" "person2@email.com"
```

**  "anything" actually means anything but line breaks

Answer (score 2):

You can look for a pattern that looks like email using `regexpr`. If a match is found, extract the relevant part using `substring`. The starting position and match length is provided by the `regexpr`

```
inds = regexpr(pattern = "<(.*@.*\\..*)>", v1)
ifelse(inds > 1,
       substring(v1, inds + 1, inds + attr(inds, "match.length") - 2),
       NA)
#[1] "personsemail@email.com" "person2@email.com"
```