# Keeping Observations in data set with a certain string - R

Tags: r, string

I'm attempting to do the following:

I have:

```r
v1 <- c("Persons Name <personsemail@email.com>","person 2 <person2@email.com>","person4",NA,"person5","Random Name <randomname@email.com>")
```

(this variable has hundreds of observations)

I want to eventually make a second variable that pulls their email and only observations with the email that makes a dataframe of the following:

```r
v2 <- unlist(as.person(v1)$email)

#which would give me: 

v2 <- c("personsemail@email.com", "person2@email.com","randomname@email.com")

#but I want a data frame of all the elements in v2 that are included in v1 such that: 

df <- data.frame(v1=c("Persons Name <personsemail@email.com>",
"person 2 <person2@email.com>",
"Random Name <randomname@email.com>"), 
v2=c("personsemail@email.com", "person2@email.com",
"randomname@email.com")
```

Note: there are many other variables in the data set too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subset `v1` first with `!is.na(v1)` and then subset it with `!sapply(v2, is.null)` to get those where you have an Email.

```
v2 <- as.person(v1)$email
cbind(v1[!is.na(v1)][!sapply(v2, is.null)], unlist(v2))
#     [,1]                                    [,2]                    
#[1,] "Persons Name <personsemail@email.com>" "personsemail@email.com"
#[2,] "person 2 <person2@email.com>"          "person2@email.com"     
#[3,] "Random Name <randomname@email.com>"    "randomname@email.com"
```

or the other way round

```
v2 <- as.person(v1)
(df <- data.frame(v1=format(v2), v2=format(v2, "email")))
#                                     v1                       v2
#1 Persons Name <personsemail@email.com> <personsemail@email.com>
#2          person 2 <person2@email.com>      <person2@email.com>
#3                               person4                         
#4                               person5                         
#5    Random Name <randomname@email.com>   <randomname@email.com>

(df <- df[df$v2!="",])
#                                     v1                       v2
#1 Persons Name <personsemail@email.com> <personsemail@email.com>
##2          person 2 <person2@email.com>      <person2@email.com>
#5    Random Name <randomname@email.com>   <randomname@email.com>
```

or

```
v2 <- as.person(v1)
df <- data.frame(v1=as.character(v2), v2=as.character(v2$email))
df <- df[df$v2!="NULL",]
```

Or you use the solution form [@d-b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57581626/10488504) to your first question.

```
inds <- regexpr(pattern = "<(.*@.*\\..*)>", v1)
v2 <- ifelse(inds > 1, substring(v1, inds + 1, inds + attr(inds, "match.length") - 2), NA)
df <- data.frame(v1, v2)
df <- df[!is.na(df$v2),]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(v1 = c("Persons Name <personsemail@email.com>","person 2 <person2@email.com>","person4",NA,"person5","Random Name <randomname@email.com>"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$v2 <- str_extract(df$v1, "<(.*)>")          #Extracts text from "<" through ">"
df$v2 <- str_replace_all(df$v2 , c("<|>"), "") #Replaces "<" or ">" with ""
df    <- na.omit(df)                           #Omits's rows with NA from the entire df. Use a different approach if you have NA in OTHER columns.

#                                     v1                     v2
#1 Persons Name <personsemail@email.com> personsemail@email.com
#2          person 2 <person2@email.com>      person2@email.com
#6    Random Name <randomname@email.com>   randomname@email.com
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is also to set the names of the `list` output from the `as.person` with the `NA` removed 'v1' (`na.omit`) and turn it to a two column `data.frame` with `stack`

```
v2 <- na.omit(v1)
stack(setNames(as.person(v2)$email, v2))[2:1]
#                               ind                 values
#1 Persons Name <personsemail@email.com> personsemail@email.com
#2          person 2 <person2@email.com>      person2@email.com
#3    Random Name <randomname@email.com>   randomname@email.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can exclude "NA" entries then you can use the following

```
df <- as.data.frame(v1)
df$v2 <- as.person(v1)$email
```